# ASP.NET MVC 5 response streaming not working. Only staging/production environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, streaming

I'm trying to continually stream data to the client with http. The code works on localhost but doesn't work in production under IIS or Apache (on Linux with mono).

When the code is on a production server it does not flush anything until I close the connection. It does work as it should on localhost.

```
 public class EventsStreamController : Controller
    {
    static EventsStreamController()
    {
        ConcurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<uint, Client>();
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<uint, Client> ConcurrentDictionary { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// http://localhost:42022/EventsStream/SendMesaage/?pollSessionID=2&message=cats
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Connect(uint pollSessionID)
    {
        var httpResponse = this.Response;

        httpResponse.BufferOutput = false;

        var client = new Client(pollSessionID);

        if (!ConcurrentDictionary.TryAdd(client.ClientId, client))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("The client is already in the dictionary.");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);

            string message;

            if (client.Messages.TryDequeue(out message))
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                httpResponse.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                httpResponse.Flush();

                if (message == "close")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// http://localhost:42022/EventsStream/connect/?pollSessionID=2
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SendMesaage(uint pollSessionID, string message)
    {
        Client client;
        if (!ConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue(pollSessionID, out client))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Client not found.");
        }

        client.Messages.Enqueue(message);

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public Client(uint clientId)
        {
            this.ClientId = clientId;
            this.Messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        }

        public uint ClientId { get; set; }

        public ConcurrentQueue<string> Messages { get; }
    }
}
```

I was using `TaskCompletionSource` to notify the waiting request that it has to stream data to the client but I changed it to checking every 2 seconds for sake of simplicity.(Also tested that on the servers, still doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send chunks, and indicate it with the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` HTTP header.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/648526/All-about-http-chunked-responses